# can't access beta app in store although my account is a tester account

Tags: apps, store, beta

i added a windows phone application as a beta app in store and add my email address as a beta tester . after app status changed to published i go to `dashboard->myApp->Details>Link to the store` and copy the url and past it to the browser but after that Store App Says me  `This item isn't available in the Store`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does usually take some time for apps to go from being published to actually being availiable to access it through the store. Normally this is <24h though.

Having the store link you will be able to see the app regardless of you are a beta tester.